# Cleaning a dataset with characters inside what should be only numeric. How do I subset these rows? I don't want to lose them

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
claim_number member_name claim_status injury_date injury_time claim_type claim_cost injury_cause gender injured_worker_~
   <chr>        <chr>       <chr>        <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      <chr>      <chr>        <chr>  <chr>           
 1 ClaimNumber~ MemberName~ Closed       A very lon~ NULL        Medical O~ 343.32     Strain       F      47              
 2 ClaimNumber~ MemberName~ Closed       56980       Late        Medical O~ 1253.04    Strain       M      50              
 3 ClaimNumber~ MemberName~ Closed       44195       Late         Indemnity  584.14     Strain       M      62              
 4 ClaimNumber~ MemberName~ Open         44194       1015        Indemnity  2573.66    Fall/Slip    F      49              
 5 ClaimNumber~ MemberName~ Closed       44194       9           Indemnity  547.39     Strain       F      51
```

I have a data set that has character text inside fields that should be numeric. For example, injury_date and injury_time. I'd like to subset/filter these to another dataframe. Take them out of the current frame but not lose the record.
Claim_cost and injured_worker_experience also have similar records.

What would be the most efficient way of subsetting these out?

Separate frame

```
claim_number member_name claim_status injury_date injury_time claim_type claim_cost injury_cause gender injured_worker_~
   <chr>        <chr>       <chr>        <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      <chr>      <chr>        <chr>  <chr>           
 1 ClaimNumber~ MemberName~ Closed       A very lon~ NULL        Medical O~ 343.32     Strain       F      47              
 2 ClaimNumber~ MemberName~ Closed       56980       Late        Medical O~ 1253.04    Strain       M      50              
 3 ClaimNumber~ MemberName~ Closed       44195       Late         Indemnity  584.14     Strain       M      62
```

Comment: Can you show your expecetd ouptut

Comment: I would just like to separate the records.

Comment: why is `1015` or `9` row removed

Comment: Those records will remain in the original dataframe.
The records set aside have text inside what should only be numeric field.

Comment: Do you want to consider all 4 columns at a time in `filter`

Comment: That is correct, all in one go

Comment: But based on your example, that would not give the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 read_csv("file path", col_type=cols(as_doubl(),as_numeric()))
```

You parse it one after the other, one at a time, try it.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to convert the columns of interest from character to numeric values and then use Base R's `complete.case()` function to filter the convert and original data frames.

```
df<-read.table(header=TRUE, text="claim_number member_name claim_status injury_date injury_time claim_type claim_cost injury_cause gender injured_worker_~
ClaimNumber~ MemberName~ Closed       'A very lon~' NULL        'Medical O~' 343.32     Strain       F      47              
ClaimNumber~ MemberName~ Closed       56980       Late        'Medical O~' 1253.04    Strain       M      50              
ClaimNumber~ MemberName~ Closed       44195       Late         Indemnity  584.14     Strain       M      62              
ClaimNumber~ MemberName~ Open         44194       1015        Indemnity  2573.66    Fall/Slip    F      49              
ClaimNumber~ MemberName~ Closed       44194       9           Indemnity  547.39     Strain       F      51")

str(df)
library(dplyr)
#create df with converted columns
#  May need to edit the array to handle all the necessary column names
df2<-df %>% mutate_at(c("injury_date", "injury_time"), as.numeric)

#retrieve rows with numeric values
df_onlyNums <- df2[complete.cases(df2), ]

#retrieve rows with non numeric values
df_char <- df[!complete.cases(df2), ]
```

Comment: @bob0901, did this answer your question?